# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'temp/edit.jpg'

Tags: python, flask

```
def download():
    try:
        return send_file("temp/edit.jpg", as_attachment=True)
    except:
        return "Unable to Download"
    finally:
        remove("temp/edit.jpg")
```

And the phote is not opned in any program

Error:-
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvTNH.png)

Comment: You probably have the photo open in another program, close it and try again

Comment: The error means what it says. You have the photo open somewhere and python cannot use it until it's not being used. Just close the application,.

Comment: @TomMcLean Thanks for response.
that image is not opened by any program

Comment: Basically in try block I send the file
and in Finally block I want to delete the file
then I get this error

Comment: is there a folder called "temp" exactly as spelled in the same file location as your python program?

Comment: @TomMcLean Yes temp dir & .py file is in same dir

Comment: How did `temp/edit.jpg` come into existence, if not by the action of another program?  If you created the file in the same script, perhaps you never closed it...

Comment: @jasonharper 
Yes no other action over the file